# Pyplot: show only first 3 lines in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running a simulation 200 times and plotting the 3 output lists as 3 lines with high transparency. This allows me to show variance between simulations.

The problem is that my legend shows 3x200 items instead of 3 items. How do I get it to show the legend for each line once?

```
for simulation in range(200):  
    plt.plot(num_s_nodes, label="susceptible", color="blue", alpha=0.02)  
    plt.plot(num_r_nodes, label="recovered", color="green", alpha=0.02)
    plt.plot(num_i_nodes, label="infected", color="red", alpha=0.02)
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 26):

add

```
plt.plot( ... , label='_nolegend_')
```

for any plotting that you do not want to show up in the legend. so in your code you may for example do:

```
..., label='_nolegend_' if simulation else 'susceptible', ...
```

and similarly for others, or if you do not like iffy code:

```
..., label=simulation and '_nolegend_' or 'susceptible',...
```

Comment: @tacaswell setting `label=None` is actually subtly different and does not remove the artist from the legend. For example: `plt.plot([0,1],[0,1],label=None); plt.plot([0,1],[1,0]); plt.legend(['justthislabel'])` will show two items in the legend. Replacing `None` with `'_nolegend_'` yields only one.

Answer (score 14):

To avoid extra logic in your plotting, use 'proxy' artists for your legend entries:

```
# no show lines for you ledgend
plt.plot([], label="susceptible", color="blue", alpha=0.02)  
plt.plot([], label="recovered", color="green", alpha=0.02)
plt.plot([], label="infected", color="red", alpha=0.02)

for simulation in range(200):
   # your actual lines
   plt.plot(num_s_nodes, color="blue", alpha=0.02)  
   plt.plot(num_r_nodes, color="green", alpha=0.02)
   plt.plot(num_i_nodes, color="red", alpha=0.02)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The good thing about this is that it also works if you use tex to parse your linelabels. I couldn't get '_nolegend_' to work with that.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just revise the arguments to `plt.legend()` as follows, and all but the first three legend entries will be hidden:

```
plt.legend(['susceptible', 'recovered', 'infected'])
```