# How to plot multiple lines from columns of an array, but give them one label

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, legend

I would like to plot multiple columns of an array and label them all the same in the plot legend. However when using:

```
x = np.loadtxt('example_array.npy')
plt.plot(x[:,1:3],label = 'first 2 lines')
plt.plot(x[:,3:5],label = '3rd and 4th lines')
plt.legend()
```

I get as many legend labels as lines I have. So the above code yields four labels in the legend box.

There must be a simple way to assign a label for a group of lines?! But I cannot find it...

I would like to avoid having to resort to

```
x = np.loadtxt('example_array.npy')
plt.plot(x[:,1],label = 'first 2 lines')
plt.plot(x[:,1:3])
plt.plot(x[:,3],label = '3rd and 4th lines')
plt.plot(x[:,3:5])
plt.legend()
```

Comment: use `label='_nolegend_'`, or do `x[:, 1:3].ravel()`

Comment: or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622060/pyplot-show-only-first-3-lines-in-legend)

Answer (score 5):

So if I get you correctly you would like to apply your labels all at once instead of typing them out in each line.

What you can do is save the elements as a array, list or similar and then iterate through them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,10)
y1 = x
y2 = x*2
y3 = x*3

lines = [y1,y2,y3]
colors  = ['r','g','b']
labels  = ['RED','GREEN','BLUE']

# fig1 = plt.figure()
for i,c,l in zip(lines,colors,labels):  
    plt.plot(x,i,c,label='l')
    plt.legend(labels)    
plt.show()
```

Which results in: 
[result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIoy.png)

Also, check out @Miguels answer here: ["Add a list of labels in Pythons matplotlib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511340/add-a-list-of-labels-in-pythons-matplotlib)

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a same label and ticks for both the columns you can just merge the columns before plotting.

```
x = np.loadtxt('example_array.npy')
plt.plot(x[:,1:3].flatten(1),label = 'first 2 lines')
plt.plot(x[:,3:5].flatten(1),label = '3rd and 4th lines')
plt.legend()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Today [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) has no numeric parameter, `order` is a letter.